# Linux No such file or directory

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jprofiler

I am trying to setup a JProfiler Agent on Remote AWS Linux.
I followed the steps from *[#### Method 2: Add agentpath to JAVA_OPTS](https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/connect-remote-jvm-jprofiler/)*.

But I get the following error:
[image]
The file is on drive. I can navigate to it.

What did I do?

1. I downloaded the JProfiler10.0.4 as targz for Linux.
2. Unzip the archive
3. Executed the command `nano ~/.bashrc`
4. I modified the content in this way. 
   [image]
5. Executed the command `source ~/.bashrc`
6. I get the error.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're actually trying to set `JAVA_OPTS`.

Todo that you have assign it to `JAVA_OPTS` and then export it. In your `.bashrc`, replace `-agentpath:"$jpPath"` with this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-agentpath:$jpPath"
```

Answer (score 0):

@crea1 is right, but I would really not use the method of modifying `JAVA_OPTS`. It's better to pass the `-agentpath` VM parameter to the VM that you are trying to profile by modifying the start script.